# Zoho ActionMailer Rails 5.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer, zoho

What configuration do I need to send email from a rails application with Zoho?

With this configuration:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtp.zoho.com',
  :port                 => 465,
  :user_name            => ENV['NOREPLY_USERNAME'],
  :password             => ENV['NOREPLY_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication       => :login,
  :ssl                  => true,
  :tls                  => true,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I get this error:
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication Failed):

With the same configuration but port 587 instead I get this error:
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: unknown protocol):

I have made sure that NOREPLY_USERNAME and NOREPLY_PASSWORD are the correct values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 465 is the correct port for Zoho. What happens if you set `:enable_starttls_auto => false`?

Comment: @ArtOfCode Same error.

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind: is 2fa enabled on your account? That makes apps have to have an app password instead of your account password.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I know about app password for 2FA and unfortunately that's not the solution. :/ 2FA is not enabled.

Comment: Then I can only think of the username or password being the issue... Let me give this a try with my own account, and I'll see what happens.

Comment: When are you getting this error? I'm not getting it, myself, but I may be doing something differently to you.

Comment: Some more things: you need to use a valid `from` value. If your Zoho email address is `abc123@zoho.com`, it won't let you send from `noreply@mydomain.com`. If your email is `noreply@mydomain.com`, it won't let you send from `abc123@mydomain.com`, or anything that isn't aliased to the address you're sending from.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I am sending an email for account activation and the error occurs right after creating an account. I get the Heroku something went wrong message, check the logs and see the error. Username and password are both correct. From value and email address is the same.

Comment: Could you edit the code that's relevant to account creation into your question? There's a small chance the issue might be in that instead of the mail code.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I can try to see next time I have the chance. Got a reply from Zoho as well. They told me to use smtp.zoho.eu instead of .com and use 465 SSL or 587 TLS. Trying that later as well.

Comment: Odd. I tried it on my account, with the settings you have here, and it worked.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Changing to smtp.zoho.eu worked as Zoho replied in the email. Should I answer my own question or just leave this comment? Not used Stack Overflow that much. Only SSl (465) worked even though Zoho told me to use 465 OR 587.

Comment: Huh. Weird. Maybe .com works for older accounts (mine's about a year old,  I'd guess) and .eu for newer accounts, or something? Definitely answer your own question with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emailed Zoho about this and they told me they checked and my email was hosted in Europe, so they told me to change to smtp.zoho.eu and use 465 SSL or 587 TLS. smtp.zoho.eu worked with 465 SSL and there are no errors and the emails are sent successfully.